# Adding the result of separate results

Tags: javascript

Thanks in advance for any replies. I am new to JavaScript and have got this far in calculating 2 results that I require. My question is how do I add both results together?

Please see first result below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkSum(e) {
        var result = 0;
        $(".checksum").each(function() {
            var i = 0;
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                i = parseFloat($(this).val());
            }

            result = result + i;
        });
        $("#resultsum").html(result * 60.60);
    }

    checkSum();
    $(".checksum").bind("keyup", checkSum);

});
```

and this is the second:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function checkSum2(e) {
        var result2 = 0;
        $(".checksum2").each(function() {
            var j = 0;
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                j = parseFloat($(this).val());
            }

            result2 = result2 + j;
        });
        $("#resultsum2").html(result2 * 14.88);
    }
    checkSum2();
    $(".checksum2").bind("keyup", checkSum2);

});
```

Comment: Your methods do not return anything, they only manipulate the DOM. Can you please explain how you would like to "combine" both "results"?

Comment: You want to add the number at #resultsum to the number at #resultsum2. Is that correct? Where do you want to store the outcome? At #resultsum3 ?

Comment: Hi, i would like to add #resultssum & #resultsum2 to, like you said, another var call #resultsum3. Thanks

Comment: I tried to combine both scripts into the one but have failed multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one line in the end of functions:

```
$("#resultsum3").html($("#resultsum").text() + $("#resultsum2").text());
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkSum(e) {
        var result = 0;
        $(".checksum").each(function() {
            var i = 0;
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                i = parseFloat($(this).val());
            }

            result = result + i;
        });
        $("#resultsum").html(result * 60.60);
      $("#resultsum3").html($("#resultsum").text() + $("#resultsum2").text());
    }

    checkSum();
    $(".checksum").bind("keyup", checkSum);
    function checkSum2(e) {
        var result2 = 0;
        $(".checksum2").each(function() {
            var j = 0;
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                j = parseFloat($(this).val());
            }

            result2 = result2 + j;
        });
        $("#resultsum2").html(result2 * 14.88);
      $("#resultsum3").html($("#resultsum").text() + $("#resultsum2").text());
    }
    checkSum2();
    $(".checksum2").bind("keyup", checkSum2);


});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ritesh, I will add it in and let you know how it looks. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: That's great, works a treat Ritesh. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've combined your snippets in to one to remove the redundant code you have. This approach will allow you to add more checksums in future (.checksum3?) and also makes sure your calculation logic is same for all.

The result is calculated in to new element whenever any of the checksums change. Try the snippet below:

```js
// function to calculate checksum
// used for both individual results as well as for total
function calcChecksum(elements) {
  let result = 0;
  elements.each( function(index, ele) {
      result = result + (parseFloat($(ele).val()) || 0)
  });
  return result;
}

// update total result
function updateTotal() {
  let total = calcChecksum($('.result'));
  $('#resultsum_total').val(total);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  // generate function for each set of checksum inputs
  function genCheckSumFn(inputSel, outputSel, multiplier) {
    return () => {
      const result = calcChecksum($(inputSel));
      $(outputSel).val(result * multiplier);
      updateTotal();
    }
  }

    //checkSum bindings
    $(".checksum").bind("keyup", 
      genCheckSumFn('.checksum','#resultsum',60.60)
    );
  
    $(".checksum2").bind("keyup", 
      genCheckSumFn('.checksum2','#resultsum2',14.88)
    );
    
    // trigger initial calculation
    $(".checksum").trigger('keyup');
    $(".checksum2").trigger('keyup');
});
```

```css
.checksum,
.checksum2{
 display: block;
}

.box {
  padding:10px 0px;
}

.box div {
  margin-top:5px;
}

.box.results input {
 color: #FFA500;
 border:0px;
 font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  Checksum
  <input class="checksum" value="10">
  <input class="checksum" value="5">
  Checksum(2)
  <input class="checksum2" value="20">
  <input class="checksum2" value="15">
<div>
<div class="box results">
<div> Resultsum: 
  <input id="resultsum" class="result" readonly>  </div>
<div> Resultsum(2): 
  <input id="resultsum2" class="result" readonly> </div>
<div> Resultsum(Total): <input id="resultsum_total" readonly> </div>
</div>
```